# C# XNA Calculate distance between rectangles (rotation-friendly)

Tags: c#, xna, collision, detection

Here's 2 methods available;

```
if(rectangle.Intersects(otherRectangle))
{
    //collision stuff
}
```

Catch: Only works with non-rotating rectangles.

```
if(Vector2.Distance(player.pos, enemy.pos) < 50)
{
    //collision stuff
}
```

Catch: Only works with circles.

**What I want is to calculate x and y in this image:** [image: problem]

**Facts**

The width and length of both rectangles is defined, along with their rotations.
I can calculate D using the Pythagorean theorem. 
But the TRUE distance is D - (X + Y).

**General approach**

Evidently x and y can be calculated using the Cosine rule. 
But I only have the width or length and the angle between the two shapes.

**Complication**

Plus, this needs to work for any rotation.
The rectangle on the left could be rotated in any direction, and x would be different depending on said rotation.

**Question**

How would I calculate x and y?
I just want an effective collision detection method more complex than bounding boxes and Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: "I just want an effective collision detection method more complex..." Be careful not to seek complexity... it will find you and you may regret it.   Seriously though, search for SAT.

Comment: So do you want to use the Pythagorean theorem or not? You could also look into `Vector2` methods, such as `Vector2.Dot()`

Comment: I need to use Pythagoras' theorem anyway to get the distance.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to rotate the line with the inverse angle and check with the axis-aligned box:

```
class RotatedBox 
{
    ...

    float CalcIntersectionLength(Vector2 lineTo) //assume that the line starts at the box' origin
    {
        Matrix myTransform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(-this.RotationAngle);
        var lineDirection = Vector2.Transform(lineTo -this.Center, myTransform);
        lineDirection.Normalize();
        var distanceToHitLeftOrRight = this.Width / 2 / Math.Abs(lineDirection.X);
        var distanceToHitTopOrBottom = this.Height / 2 / Math.Abbs(lineDirection.Y);
        return Math.Min(distanceToHitLeftOrRight, distanceToHitTopOrBottom);
    }
}
```

Now you can calculate the actual distance with

```
 var distance = (box1.Center - box2.Center).Length
                - box1.CalcIntersectionLength(box2.Center)
                - box2.CalcIntersectionLength(box1.Center);
```

Be sure that the rotation direction matches your visualization.

Comment: Center and lineTo would be what?

Comment: Center is the box' center and `lineTo` the line's target.

Comment: I just implemented this in a test application. It works. Make sure that `Width` belongs to the unrotated x-axis, `Height` belongs to the unrotated y-axis. Make sure that your visualization matches the data (i.e. correct center point, correct rotation direction). The center point in the video seems to be a bit off. I drew the sample box with `sb.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)Center.X, (int)Center.Y, (int)Width, (int)Height), null, Color.White, RotationAngle, new Vector2(Texture.Width / 2, Texture.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);`. `RotationAngle` has to be in radians.